# как сделать кастомизированнный синхронный скроллинг в таблице?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать синхронный скролбар? я использую плагин mCustomScrollbar.
Пробую реализовать синхронный скролл с помощью данного плагина, пока что не получилось, может кто уже имел дело с этим. Подскажите.

мой код внизу

```js
$('#t-assort-h').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis:"x",
  scrollButtons:{enable:true},
  theme:"3d",
  scrollbarPosition:"outside",
  callbacks:{
   whileScrolling:function(){ 

    

   },
  }
 
  
 });

 $('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis:"x",
  scrollButtons:{enable:true},
  theme:"3d",
  scrollbarPosition:"outside",
  callbacks:{
   whileScrolling:function(){ 
   

    


   },
  }
 });
```

```css
.stock  table {border-spacing: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
 }
 #t-main-h,
 #tmain-body {
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
 }
 #first-col-h, 
 #first-col-body {
    width: 60px;
    vertical-align: top;
 }
 #t-assort-h {
    height: 50px; 
 }
 .r-blcok {
    font-size: 18px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #e0e0e0;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
 }
 .nal-block {
    text-align: center;
}
.nal-block, .left-col-cell {
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}
 .head-name {
    width: 70px !important;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    white-space: wrap-all;
    padding: 10px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>





  <div id="stock">
    <div id="d-thead">
      <table id="t-main-h">
        <tr>
          <td id="first-col-h">&nbsp;</td>
          <td>
            <div id="t-assort-h">
              <table id="thead" class="scroll-pane">
                <tr>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 1</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 2</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 3</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 4</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 5</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 6</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 7</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 8</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 9</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 10</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 11</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 12</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 13</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 14</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 15</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 16</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 17</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 18</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 19</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 20</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 21</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 22</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 23</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 24</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 25</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 26</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 27</div>
                  </td>
                  <td class="r-blcok">
                    <div class="head-name">Заголовок 28</div>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="d-tbody">
      <table id="tmain-body">
        <tr>
          <td id="first-col-body" style="vertical-align: middle;">
            <div class="name-row">Строка 1</div>
          </td>
          <td>
            <div id="t-asort-b">
              <table id="tbody">
                <tr style="height: 120px;">
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 1</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 2</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 3</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 4</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 5</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 6</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 7</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 8</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 9</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 10</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 11</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 12</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 13</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 14</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 15</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 16</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 17</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 19</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 20</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 21</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 22</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 23</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 24</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 25</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 26</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 27</td>
                  <td class="nal-block">Содержание 28</td>
                </tr>
              </table>
            </div>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы добиться более или менее синхронной прокрутки стандартными средствами, добавьте опцию `scrollInertia:0` в код инициализации скроллбаров и `callbacks:false` - в метод `scrollTo`:

```js
$('#t-assort-h').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  scrollInertia: 0,
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      $('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", this.mcs.left, {
        callbacks: false
      });
    }
  }
});

$('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  scrollInertia: 0,
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      $('#t-asort-h').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", this.mcs.left, {
        callbacks: false
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.stock table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#t-main-h,
#tmain-body {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-col-h,
#first-col-body {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#t-assort-h {
  height: 50px;
}

.r-blcok {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nal-block {
  text-align: center;
}

.nal-block,
.left-col-cell {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.head-name {
  width: 84px !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: wrap-all;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="stock">
  <div id="d-thead">
    <table id="t-main-h">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-h">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-assort-h">
            <table id="thead" class="scroll-pane">
              <tr>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 6</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 13</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 15</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 16</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 17</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 18</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 19</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 20</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 21</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 22</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 23</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 24</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 25</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 26</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 27</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 28</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="d-tbody">
    <table id="tmain-body">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-body" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="name-row">Строка 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-asort-b">
            <table id="tbody">
              <tr style="height: 120px;">
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 1</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 2</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 3</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 4</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 5</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 6</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 7</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 8</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 9</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 10</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 11</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 12</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 13</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 14</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 15</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 16</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 17</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 19</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 20</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 21</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 22</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 23</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 24</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 25</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 26</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 27</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 28</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Чтобы добиться **ПОЛНОЙ** синхронности, нужно лезть в js-файл и вносить изменения в нем. А именно:

1. открываем файл jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js;
2. переходим на строку [#643](https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/blob/master/js/uncompressed/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js#L643) (на момент 28.08.2017 );
3. видим там следующий код - `timeout:60, /* scroll-to delay */`;
4. меняем его на `timeout:0, /* scroll-to delay */`
5. сохраняем изменения, перезагружаем страницу и видим результат - **полная синхронность** в работе 2х скроллбаров.

Рабочий пример (модифицированный jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js загружен на [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B3bKlFSRkNdsX3FtaGdlaXl3Tnc)):

```js
$('#t-assort-h').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  scrollInertia: 0,
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      $('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", this.mcs.left, {
        callbacks: false
      });
    }
  }
});

$('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  scrollInertia: 0,
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      $('#t-asort-h').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo", this.mcs.left, {
        callbacks: false
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.stock table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#t-main-h,
#tmain-body {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-col-h,
#first-col-body {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#t-assort-h {
  height: 50px;
}

.r-blcok {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nal-block {
  text-align: center;
}

.nal-block,
.left-col-cell {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.head-name {
  width: 84px !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: wrap-all;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Модифицированный jquery.mCustomScrollbar.js -->
<script src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&confirm=no_antivirus&id=0B3bKlFSRkNdsX3FtaGdlaXl3Tnc"></script>
<div id="stock">
  <div id="d-thead">
    <table id="t-main-h">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-h">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-assort-h">
            <table id="thead" class="scroll-pane">
              <tr>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 6</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 13</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 15</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 16</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 17</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 18</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 19</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 20</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 21</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 22</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 23</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 24</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 25</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 26</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 27</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 28</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="d-tbody">
    <table id="tmain-body">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-body" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="name-row">Строка 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-asort-b">
            <table id="tbody">
              <tr style="height: 120px;">
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 1</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 2</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 3</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 4</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 5</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 6</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 7</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 8</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 9</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 10</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 11</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 12</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 13</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 14</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 15</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 16</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 17</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 19</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 20</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 21</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 22</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 23</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 24</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 25</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 26</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 27</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 28</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариант, при котором первый скролл скроллит оба блока. Второй скролл присинхронизировать нельзя, потому что в этом случае его изменение первого скролла будет вызывать вызывать коллбэк, по которому будет меняться второй скролл и так очень долго. В данном случае я бы скрыл второй скролл css-сом.

```js
$('#t-assort-h').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      $('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar('scrollTo', this.mcs.left, {
        scrollEasing: "linear",
        scrollInertia: 0
      });
    }
  }
});

$('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {

    }
  }
});
```

```css
.stock table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#t-main-h,
#tmain-body {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-col-h,
#first-col-body {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#t-assort-h {
  height: 50px;
}

.r-blcok {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nal-block {
  text-align: center;
}

.nal-block,
.left-col-cell {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.head-name {
  width: 84px !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: wrap-all;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="stock">
  <div id="d-thead">
    <table id="t-main-h">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-h">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-assort-h">
            <table id="thead" class="scroll-pane">
              <tr>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 6</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 13</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 15</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 16</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 17</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 18</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 19</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 20</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 21</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 22</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 23</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 24</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 25</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 26</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 27</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 28</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="d-tbody">
    <table id="tmain-body">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-body" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="name-row">Строка 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-asort-b">
            <table id="tbody">
              <tr style="height: 120px;">
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 1</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 2</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 3</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 4</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 5</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 6</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 7</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 8</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 9</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 10</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 11</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 12</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 13</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 14</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 15</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 16</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 17</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 19</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 20</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 21</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 22</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 23</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 24</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 25</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 26</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 27</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 28</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#t-assort-h').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  callbacks: {
    whileScrolling: function() {
      var indent = this.mcs.left;
      $('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",indent,{
        callbacks:false
      });
    }
  }
});

$('#t-asort-b').mCustomScrollbar({
  axis: "x",
  scrollButtons: {
    enable: true
  },
  theme: "3d",
  scrollbarPosition: "outside",
  callbacks: {
     whileScrolling: function() {
      var indent = this.mcs.left;
      $('#t-asort-h').mCustomScrollbar("scrollTo",indent,{
        callbacks:false
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.stock table {
  border-spacing: 0;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

#t-main-h,
#tmain-body {
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}

#first-col-h,
#first-col-body {
  width: 60px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#t-assort-h {
  height: 50px;
}

.r-blcok {
  font-size: 18px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}

.nal-block {
  text-align: center;
}

.nal-block,
.left-col-cell {
  border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
}

.head-name {
  width: 84px !important;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: wrap-all;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/3.1.5/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.min.js"></script>
<div id="stock">
  <div id="d-thead">
    <table id="t-main-h">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-h">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-assort-h">
            <table id="thead" class="scroll-pane">
              <tr>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 1</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 2</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 3</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 4</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 5</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 6</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 7</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 8</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 9</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 10</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 11</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 12</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 13</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 14</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 15</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 16</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 17</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 18</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 19</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 20</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 21</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 22</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 23</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 24</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 25</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 26</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 27</div>
                </td>
                <td class="r-blcok">
                  <div class="head-name">Заголовок 28</div>
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="d-tbody">
    <table id="tmain-body">
      <tr>
        <td id="first-col-body" style="vertical-align: middle;">
          <div class="name-row">Строка 1</div>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div id="t-asort-b">
            <table id="tbody">
              <tr style="height: 120px;">
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 1</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 2</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 3</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 4</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 5</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 6</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 7</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 8</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 9</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 10</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 11</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 12</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 13</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 14</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 15</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 16</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 17</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 19</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 20</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 21</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 22</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 23</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 24</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 25</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 26</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 27</td>
                <td class="nal-block">Содержание 28</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>



</body>

</html>
```